# Can ScratchJr work with WeDo 2.0?

Tags: wedo, scratch

Now that [ScratchJr](https://www.scratchjr.org/) is available on the tablet.

Is it possible to use it to control a WeDo 2.0 robot?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can use only Scratch 2.0